# Print retry count with @Retryable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am using @Retryable on a method like this :-

```
@Retryable( value = SQLException.class, 
      maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
void testMethod(String abc) throws SQLException{
//some method body that could throw sql exception
};
```

And i want to print the count of retry , with a message like :

```
Retry Number : 1
Retry Number : 2
...
Retry Number : 5
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can add below code:

```
@Retryable( value = SQLException.class, 
      maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
void testMethod(String abc) throws SQLException{
log.info("Retry Number : {}",RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount());
};
```

RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount() will give you the retry count on flow.

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the correct answer here.
Simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 12):

you can add retryListener

```
    @Retryable( value = SQLException.class, maxAttempts = 5, 
                backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100), listeners = {"retryListener"})
    void testMethod(String abc) throws SQLException{
    //some method body that could throw sql exception
    };
```

retryListener should like below, you can print retry count on error.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
class MyRetryListener implements RetryListener {

    // Called after the final attempt (succesful or not).
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context,
                                               RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {

        log.debug("Retry closing..");
        super.close(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    // Called after every unsuccessful attempt at a retry
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred, Retry Count {} ", context.getRetryCount());
        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    // Called before the first attempt in a retry
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context,
                                                 RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
        log.debug("Retry opening..");
        return super.open(context, callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: This listener is incorrect; the open method is not called when an "Exception Occurred"; it is called once, at the beginning; further, close does not mean "Unable to recover...", it is called at the end, regardless of outcome - see the Javadocs. The listener is called within the scope of the retry operation: `open -> call target one or more times until successful or retries exhausted -> close`.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks for information, updated logs and add comments, 
here a javadoc [RetryListenerSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/listener/RetryListenerSupport.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can also enable logging for 'org.springframework.retry' package

application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework:
      retry: DEBUG
```